# Binding of control visibility to ViewModel property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm in the process of converting a fairly large WPF app from three-layer into MVVM, and in the process learning MVVM. So far, I haven't delved into too much detail around Bindings (etc), so bear with me.

I'm trying to bind the System.Windows.Visibility of multiple controls to a public property ("State") of the ViewModel. When the parent TabItem loads, the State property is read and handled as desired. When subsequent changes to the property are made, however, they appear to be ignored. I've (re-re-re-)checked Bindings, debugged the Converters, etc, and this is driving me crazy.

ViewModel:

```
public class MarketingListViewModel: IDisposable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private UiState state;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public UiState State 
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            if (state != value)
            {
                state = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
    }

    public MarketingListViewModel() 
    {
        State = UiState.View;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) 
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

View:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
         mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfCrm.tabListManager" xmlns:DPH="clr-namespace:DPH" >

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DPH:MarketingListViewModel x:Key="listVM" />
    <!-- Note that the above line is giving me an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error -->
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="gridMain" DataContext="{StaticResource listVM}" >

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10"
            Style="{StaticResource WidgetStyle}" >
        <Grid x:Name="gridListManagement" >
            <Label x:Name="labelManageLists" Content="Manage Lists" MouseDown="labelManageLists_MouseDown"
                Style="{StaticResource WidgetTitleStyle}"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <Label x:Name="llNewList" Content="new" MouseDown="llNewList_MouseDown"
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkLabelStyle}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                <Label x:Name="llCloseManageLists" Content="close" MouseDown="llCloseManageLists_MouseDown" 
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkLabelStyle}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>

            <Label x:Name="labelListName" Content="Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <ComboBox x:Name="cbLists" SelectedIndex="-1" SelectionChanged="cbLists_SelectionChanged" IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllMarketingLists}" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                          SelectedValuePath="Id"
                          Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource ViewStateToVisibilityConverter} }"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbListName" 
                         Text="{Binding Path=OList.Name}"
                         Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource EditStateToVisibilityConverter} }"/>
            </Grid>

            <Label x:Name="labelListDescription" Content="Description" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="textblockListDescription" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="{Binding Path=OList.Notes}"
                           Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource ViewStateToVisibilityConverter} }"
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                <TextBox x:Name="tbListDescription" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Text="{Binding Path=OList.Notes}"
                         Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource EditStateToVisibilityConverter} }"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            </Grid>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Button x:Name="buttonEditList" Content="Edit" Click="buttonEditList_Click"
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource ViewStateToVisibilityConverter} }"
                        Width="60" Margin="3" />
                <Button x:Name="buttonSaveList" Content="Save" Click="buttonSaveList_Click"
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource EditStateToVisibilityConverter} }"
                        Width="60" Margin="3" />
                <Button x:Name="buttonCancel" Content="Cancel" Click="buttonCancel_Click" 
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=State, Converter={StaticResource EditStateToVisibilityConverter} }"
                        Width="60" Margin="3" />
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

And the code-behind has a few methods like:

```
    private void buttonEditList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        listVM.State = UiState.Edit;
    }
```

Does anyone have ideas on why the controls aren't updating their visibility after the State change?

Kind thanks,

DPH

EDIT -- Converters:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(WpfCrm.UiState), typeof(System.Windows.Visibility))]
public class EditStateToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        UiState state = (UiState)value;
        if (state == UiState.View) return Visibility.Collapsed;
        else return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

[ValueConversion(typeof(WpfCrm.UiState), typeof(System.Windows.Visibility))]
public class ViewStateToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        UiState state = (UiState)value;
        if (state == UiState.View) return Visibility.Visible;
        else return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your converter code

Comment: Do you declare listVM somewhere in code-behind?

Comment: Yes -- listVM = new MarketingListViewModel(); -- right after InitializeComponent() in the view's constructor.

Comment: Thank you all very much! Fifteen hours of head-banging resolved by SO in ten minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be used two different instances of your view model, one declared and used in XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DPH:MarketingListViewModel x:Key="listVM" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource listVM}" >
```

and one in code-behind (from comment):

```
listVM = new MarketingListViewModel();
```

You should of course be using only one. So change your code behind declaration to

```
listVM = (MarketingListViewModel)Resources["listVM"];
```

Comment: I'd put this in the constructor in place of the code that creates a new VM

Comment: @TonyVitabile Where's your point? Original comment was " listVM = new MarketingListViewModel(); -- right after InitializeComponent() in the view's constructor". I wrote "change your code behind declaration", so it's obviously also in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

OK, there is a mistake. You declare listVM as

```
var listVM = new MarketingListViewModel();
```

But this is not the listVM from your XAML. In XAML you have created another instance of MarketingListViewModel. So, when you try to change listVM that was declared in code, nothing happens because this object is not DataContext of your Grid.

In your Click handler you have to write the following:

```
private void buttonEditList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    var _listVM = (MarketingListViewModel)FindResource("listVM");
    _listVM.State = UiState.Edit;
}
```

OR replace your listVM declaration in code-behind with this one:

```
listVM = (MarketingListViewModel)FindResource("listVM");
```

Then you won't need to change event handlers.

Hope, it helps.